# Why is onClick not called for costume ImageButton?

Tags: android, listener, onclicklistener

I am currently extending a ImageButton in android as such :

```
public class Pen extends ImageButton {
    public Pen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Now I am setting  Pen");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in xml file I do :

```
  .....

   <com.example.testsetimagebmp.Pen
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pen"
        android:background="@drawable/pen" />

   ....
```

Finally in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Pen myImgbutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myImgbutton = (Pen) findViewById(R.id.pen);

    myImgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("I am form MainActivity onClick");
        }
    });

    // ....
}
```

Whenever I try to press on the ImageButton onClick Never gets called. But When replace costume Pen with ImageButton everything works. Am I missing something while inheriting from the ImageButton?

Comment: How is your code even getting compiled? You are not returning anything from `onTouchEvent()`.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Sorry copy paste error

Comment: `Then in xml file I do : ..... ....` - it's called Morse Code Programming :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski :) Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I try to press on the ImageButton onClick Never gets called

Click is sequence of two events: `ACTION_DOWN` and (next) `ACTION_UP`. As you added your `onTouchEvent()` then no other code than yours knows that view has been tapped, not to mention clicked. So instead of doing `return true;` (which tells that you handled that MotionEvent and system knows there's no point of handing it to any other listener) you should call original code `return super.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);` to let it track taps and react to clicks or long clicks as it used to and return what it would produce:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Now I am setting  Pen");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Yup it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

By returning `true` you are saying that you've consumed `Touch` event and no input events will be delegated to other listeners further.
You should use -

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Now I am setting  Pen");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```